# Haskell: What does the : operator mean in an anonymous function within map?

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function

I got trouble to understand this line:

`combs val = [] : concatMap (\w -> map (:w) val) (combs val)`

The purpose is to create all combinations possible. It is an infinite list. (combs :: [a] -> [[a]])

I don't understand the anonymous function: `\w -> map (:w) val`

What does `(:w)` mean? What kind of mapping function is that? In my perception \w must be a list? Is it a concatination? I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(:w)` is a *section*. It is equivalent to

```
\x -> x:w
```

This holds for every infix operator. We have

```
(+ w) = (\x -> x+w)
(* w) = (\x -> x*w)
(/ w) = (\x -> x/w)
```

and so on. (Only exception: `(-x)` is unary minus, so it is a number and not a function)

This also applies to sections where the infix operator is on the other side:

```
(w/) = (\x -> w/x)
```

In your specific case, `map (:w)` prepends each element of the input list to the list `w`, e.g.

```
map (:w) [a,b,c] = [a:w, b:w, c:w]
```